# Gradle Module Execution Order

Tags: module, dependencies, gradle, dependency-management

I have a gradle project with two modules.

The first module (A) produces an archive that the second module (B) makes use of. I've defined the `settings.gradle` file so that A is seen before B.

At the end of A, there is an `install` task that is called which will make the archive available for B, however the `install` task won't execute until *all* modules build.

When I use A's build file, or set the build command `-p` it will still try to find dependencies for project B. I don't want to do this!

How can I set this up so that module B will wait completely for module A to finish?

Answer (score 2):

> I've defined the settings.gradle file so that A is seen before B.

Order doesn't matter here.

> At the end of A, there is an install task that is called which will make the archive available for B

The correct way to handle this is to make the outputs of A available to B via a *project dependency*. In the simplest case, B's `build.gradle` will contain the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":A") // could be something other than 'compile'
}
```

> When I use A's build file, or set the build command -p it will still try to find dependencies for project B.

Most likely there is a problem with one of your build scripts, namely that it does work in the *configuration phase* that should be done in the *execution phase*.

> How can I set this up so that module B will wait completely for module A to finish?

There is no good way. Gradle executes a graph of tasks, not a list of projects. As long as task dependencies are correct, the former will have no drawbacks, only advantages. Often, Gradle can figure out task dependencies automatically (especially between projects).

Comment: the dependency trick doesn't work if the module is only a distribution project, unfortunately